# exponential distribution to discrete distribution transformation?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-distribution

If a random variable $X$ has an exponential distribution determined by parameter $\lambda = 1$, provide a function $t$ such that $t(X)$ has the distribution of the outcome of flipping a fair, six-sided cube.

I don't know how to approach this question. The first thing that jumps out at me is that we are attempting to transform a continuous random variable to a discrete one on the interval $[1, 6]$. Any suggestions/derivations would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: A very general method is that you first transform the exponential distribution, to the standard uniform distribution by its CDF $F_X$. Then use the quantile function (inverse of the CDF) of the discrete uniform to transform this uniform distribution. So the required function $t$ could be the composition of these two function. Note that the choice of $t$ is not unique here. In this problem, actually you only need to find $6$ sets, $A_1, \ldots, A_6$, such that they formed a partition of the support of $X$, i.e. $(0, +\infty)$, and $\Pr\{X \in A_i\}=1/6$. Then you assign $t(X)=i$ if $X\in A_i$.

Comment: @BGM Thank you very much for your response. I am with you up to transforming $X$ as given to some random variable that is distributed according to $Unif(1, 6)$. However, I lose you after that, ie. how to explicitly construct t & make the jump from something being distributed as $Unif(1, 6)$ to finding those 6 sets.

Comment: @BGM never mind, I think I figured it out. It's just identifying quartiles of the exponential distribution, isn't it? But this time with six (1/6, 2/6, 3/6, ... for the CDF), not the usual four.

Comment: Yes I think you have get that. But as you can see you can always swap the assignment, say $t(X) = 7 - i$ if $X \in A_i$ is also another valid function. Taking the quantiles at $1/6, \ldots, 5/6$ are the most typical way, but the Borel set $A_i$ can be much more general.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a similar situation. The [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) of $X$ is $\log2$, i.e., $P(X<\log2)=P(X\ge\log2)=.5$. So the function $x\mapsto t'(x)$ that takes the value $0$ when $x<\log2$ and $1$ when $x>\log2$ is like a fair coin flip.